# Magento Product Url Rewrite issues

Tags: url-rewrite

I have a magento site.i following issue with the product url.

```
 - I have product A with url key as 'a'.
 - I have product B with url key as 'b'.

When i hit www.mysite.com/a it will redirect to www.mysite.com/b.

But when i hit product a from any category like www.mysite.com/category1/a it is redirecting to correct product.

Please Help Me.
```

Answer (score 2):

That can happen if you edit URL Keys on the product as it tries to remember the previous URL Key.

Use URL Rewrite Management to review and edit any URL changes you need to make. Remember to reindex catalog urls.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/urlrewrite/index